# nginx rtmp conf using argument

Tags: nginx, rtmp, nginx-config

i configure server using nginx - rtmp plugin module.
The Problem is rtmp publish.

rtmp plugin module support "on_publish_done" command.
https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_publish_done

and i want like this.
`on_publish_done http://MY_SERVER/$APP/$NAME ;`
In nginx configure file(nginx.conf) can use $arg_XXX value. 
But my conf-file can not observe value. Observe just string "$arg_app", "$arg_name".
How to observe $arg_app, $arg_name ?? 
this is my conf file.

```
# HTTP can be used for accessing RTMP stats
http {
    access_log /Users/steve/dev/workspace/nginx/logs/access.log;
    server {
    listen      8080;
      location /local_redirect {
        rewrite ^.*$ newname? permanent;
    }
      location /cast {
        # Serve HLS fragments
        types {
          application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
          video/mp2t ts;
        }
        root /Users/steve/dev/workspace/nginx/tmp;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

      }
    }
}
rtmp {
    access_log /PATH/nginx/logs/rtmp-access.log;
    server {
      listen 1935;
      chunk_size 4000;
      application cast {
                live on;
                publish_notify on;
                hls on;
                hls_path /PATH/workspace/nginx/out;
                hls_nested on;
                hls_fragment 1s;
                hls_playlist_length 12s;
      }
      notify_method get;
      on_publish_done http://127.0.0.1:5000/$arg_app/$arg_name ; ##PROBLEM HERE!!
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of $arg_app pass "$app" and "$name" only

Answer (score 0):

[the image below shows that a variable with an underscore which is located between character r and b works well!  ][1]

for me the code below using bash command with a -c flag works! try it bro

```
exec_publish_done bash -c "/var/hls/ex.sh ${name}";
```

Comment: Your image link didn’t come through. Can you edit your answer to include the image? (Unless the image is of code, in which cases it should be included as text, not a screenshot.)